# Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

Tags: java, php, android

I am getting the following errors in my logs. I am trying to generate an API request from android to PHP

```
POST /ws/cal_distance.php HTTP/1.1" 200 330 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"
```

I am also receiving similar error codes with other files.

```
"POST /ws/checklogin.php HTTP/1.1" 200 457 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"
"POST /ws/get_driver_status.php HTTP/1.1" 200 455 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"
"POST /ws/update_driver_status.php HTTP/1.1" 200 238 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"
"POST /ws/cal_distance.php HTTP/1.1" 200 330 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"
```

I need to fix this any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Apache HTTP client on Android is deprecated. Use something else.

Comment: @M Abu Bakar Khan . Hi,I am getting same error .Did you find any solution  ?